# how to fix "Failed cleaning build dir for scipy"

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, conv-neural-network, scipy-optimize-minimize

This is the error I'm facing while installing scipy=1.1.0:

[image: error]

I'm working on Python version 3.8 and want to install Scipy=1.1.0 using VScode but I'm unable to install it. It is throwing an error.

I tried many ways like I use `pip install wheel` before trying `pip install scipy=1.1.0`

Comment: please post code and text, not pictures

Comment: please post code and text, not pictures

Answer (score 0):

**Scipy 1.1.0** is a very older version and released in the year of 2018 (as mentioned in the release [history](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#history)) and will not be supported by `Python 3.8`.

You can either use the latest **scipy 1.9.3** (released in the year 2022) or can install and access scipy 1.10 by downgrading the python version to `3.7`.